# How to view an SVG image on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, svg

I'm working with a bioinformatics visualization tool, which saves a biological pathway as an SVG image.

I now want to view the SVG image... but am having some trouble doing so. I tried opening it as a file in both Chrome and Firefox, but in both browsers it just opens a blank page. I clicked on "View page source" and I'm able to see the XML data of the SVG image, but still, I want to see the image itself as a graphic.

What's the easiest way to view the image as a graphic? I understand that I can embed it in an HTML page and view it that way... but that's not at all convenient, if I have to create an HTML page each time I save a pathway as an image.

By the way, I'm using a 64-bit Mac OSX version 10.8.4.

Comment: Browsers should be able to just show it. I wonder why that's not the case for you. Can you upload an example?

Comment: Yes I thought that Firefox or at least Chrome should be able to view it. Is there a way to upload on Superuser? Or would I have to upload on a temporary hosting site?

Comment: No, sorry, but any file hosting site or Dropbox or something would be possible, of course.

Comment: I was able to open a smaller SVG file in Chrome. Could it possibly be the image size? The SVG file I'm unable to open is 20 MB.

Comment: Have you tried opening it in Inkscape?

Comment: I just tried opening it in Inkscape. It opened... but it's very slow and unusable. It seems like Inkscape is on the verge of crashing :( After all it's a 20MB SVG file.

Comment: Yeah, after opening it in Inkscape the software is completely frozen. I can't even use the menu tools (like the 'File' menu).

Comment: 20 MB is *a lot* for a vector image.

Comment: I don't have OS X so I'm not familiar with the options available, but on Linux I would just create a small ramfs, or ramdisk. When I want to view a file I'd copy it to the ramfs, then open it, when done, remove it from the ramfs. Perhaps OS X has an option similar to `sudo mount -t ramfs -o size=40m ramfs /media/ramfs1` ?

Comment: 20 MB is really large. If the file size turns out to be the cause of the problem, you might have luck using SVGO, a command line tool that can drastically and losless shrink the SVG file.

Comment: Nowadays any browser is capable of rendering .svg, any browser you might be using anyway, at least on Windows, though probably this also applies to Mac OSX...

Answer (score 53):

I am pretty happy with [Gapplin](http://gapplin.wolfrosch.com/). It can convert (export) SVG images to other image formats (e.g. PNG) too.

Comment: Not available in the UK apparently :(

Comment: @JMK Thats weird, its available in Ireland anyway. I was able to download it from the App Store.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to use this to convert via the context menu in the finder?

Comment: @JMK It is now!

Answer (score 44):

A simple way is to use Quick Look in Mac, simply **press space key** on the keyboard.

Comment: But does Preview work with SVG files?

Comment: Mac spotlight (Command+SpaceBar) does preview for svg files. Although not the best solution.

Comment: @Glorfindel it does for me in Catalina (I'm on 10.15.6; haven't tried other versions).

Comment: My copy of Preview 11.0 (999.4) running on MacOS Catalina 10.15.2 does not open SVG files.  I am pretty sure what's gong on here is that Billy Wang is talking about the (uncapitalized) image preview feature of *Spotlight*.  (Spotlight is the thing accessed by pressing CMD-SPACE on Mac.) This is different from the (capitalized) *Preview* app, which is used for opening and manipulating image files.

Comment: More precisely, Billy probably mean the preview in Finder, when you hit Space while a file is selected.

Comment: And @Florian the name of that utility summoned using the space bar is **Quick Look** https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/view-and-edit-files-with-quick-look-mh14119/mac

Comment: its apps need to download first ? because i dont see the apps ( macbook pro m1 )

Answer (score 11):

If you're part of the unlucky few where double clicking an .svg from Finder or opening it from the command line like `open filename.svg` just opens your svg file source in a text editor (and you wanted to see it visually), it appears possible to view them in a browser these days.  What has happened is you installed a text editor and it "took over" as the default app to open for those file types.

Navigate in your web browser to its location, ex: `file:///Users/my_username/...` full URL should have look like `file:///Users/username/folder/folder/my_file.svg` you can start by just putting `file://` in your browser URL then navigate to it.

This will "open it" visually in any major web browser.  Alternatively right click on it in `Finder` and select "open with" and select a browser.

Comment: Great idea using the browser! The svg may also be drag&dropped on the browser window.

Answer (score 10):

I needed a nearly-portable solution to view SVG files (vector export from Google Drawings, which doesn't print large images well) since my Mac is locked down to prevent typical software installation, App Store access and Chrome extensions.  Fortunately, I can run Homebrew. That led me to install [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/download/mac-os/) from Homebrew using this command.

```
brew install --cask inkscape
```

Comment: This fails at the moment https://github.com/caskformula/homebrew-caskformula/issues/97

Answer (score 5):

There is a nice new free SVG editor with you can get from the Mac App Store or the Chrome Web Store. Give it a try, it's <strike>free</strike> now $9.99 on the App Store.

[Boxy SVG](https://boxy-svg.com) 
 - the scalable vector graphics editor

[image]

Comment: [macSVG](https://github.com/dsward2/macSVG) is free + Open Source.

Comment: @Bruno sound cool, may give it a try, however I still using Boxy SVG to this day, so I very much recommend it !

Answer (score 3):

[GraphicConverter](http://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/key-features/import-and-export-formats/) has always been my standby 'any format' viewer & editor - it does SVG too
*Caveat:* Not free & there may be other apps that can do it.

Comment: I see. Yes we're looking for a free software (or browser function).

Comment: Adobe used to make a viewer plugin... dumped summarily in 2009 http://www.adobe.com/devnet/svg/adobe-svg-viewer-download-area.html ... one reason Apple won't use Adobe formats natively, they drop support or change formats at any time.

Comment: It might be time to be looking at a newer format, before you lose the ability to open/edit in future

Comment: The software I use only lets you download the visualization in SVG format.

Comment: I'd be inclined to poke upwards towards management, about a historic format - not going to be good for archiving

Comment: @Tetsujin SVG isn't a "historic" format, or an Adobe one. It's an open standard that's in very wide current use; if anything, support for it is increasing.

Comment: GraphicConverter has a demo version (free), which handles this just fine..

Answer (score 3):

I found that applications would refuse to open an SVG on OSX unless I gave it the correct extension. So I renamed the file to, in my case, `pprof.svg`. I was then able to "open with" Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered SVG Converter by Ohanaware on the Mac App Store.  It converts to a number of formats and can crop before converting.  Opening an SVG image gives you a nice window that shows the image and conversion is optional.

Comment: @Scott it does give a preview.  This is where the cropping can occur.

Comment: Thanks for responding  and  editing your answer.

Answer (score 2):

On macOS 10.12, I have been working with SVG files drawn using Inkscape and my own hand-written SVG files composed in a text editor.

Initially the Inkscape files would open as images in a web browser, in Preview, and via Quick Look (spacebar in the Finder), but my hand-written files would not. Instead they were displayed as raw source XML.

It turned out that the critical difference between the two was that my hand-written files were missing `xmlns`:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width=… …>
…
</svg>
```

Once I added a namespace declaration to `<svg>`, macOS recognised my hand-written files as SVG images and displayed them as such.

Perhaps your bioinformatics visualization tool has also omitted this declaration?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this [photo viewer](https://www.widsmob.com/viewer) to browse SVG images on Mac with ease.

Comment: Almost went with this option, turns out I had "icon preview off" in finder view options. That solved my problem of dealing with hundreds of SVGs in a folder

Answer (score 1):

Quick no-install option:

1. Preview it in finder with `spacebar`
2. Maximize the window (top left)
3. Take screenshot with cmd-shift-3 or similar

Comment: The best answer ever! :) No additional software, pure macOS :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pressing spacebar is noted on the answers but I was interested to know how one can bring that from command line without the finder and turned out that be can done using

```
qlmanage -p filename.svg
```

But apparently it needs an interactive shell to work as I couldn't issue it from an app/script I wanted the functionality, to me it quickly turned out, my editor, IntelliJ Idea, was able to show SVGs itself so I'm using that anyway guess however someone will see find how one can bring qlmanage from a shell correctly also.

Comment: Also to note, qlmanage is also able to render SVG to PNG or something but I didn't just test it.

Answer (score 0):

I love the tool ImageMagick it is available from the apt repo for linix as well as a GitHub.

Edit:
It is a simple command-line utility that utilizes the file extensions, or user flags to override to convert images, with the first file being converted (and copied ) into the second file in the argument list.
Source: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick

Comment: Explaining how this tool answers the question would make it more helpful. Also, please read our Help section where there's an article explaining how best to recommend software.

Comment: This is a quite non-Mac answer to a Mac-specific question. Mac does not have APT. It does, however, have third-party package managers likeHomebrew, MacPorts, Fink… all of which I believe offer ImageMagick (e.g., `brew install imagemagick`). The ImageMagick website itself recommends installing via Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

For new versions of Chrome, it can render SVG files directly(I just tried with Chrome 79).

Answer (score 0):

Gimp is **free** and worked for me. https://www.gimp.org/

Answer (score 0):

Most internet browsers can view SVGs.

right click the svg -> open in safari, then it will open in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

svg format is an XML format. So you do not need to convert it into html. You should be able to directly view it in a browser.
You can confirm this by opening the file in a text editor and checking the encoding.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).